# How to hide a form from another form by clicking a button there in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Hide();
```

**Here form1 is not hiding and btnLogin is in form2**

Comment: Are both forms in the same process?

Comment: what u want first show frm frm.Show() after hide using  frm.Hide(),

Comment: I have opened the second form by clicking a button from first form. now i want to hide the first form by clicking a button in second form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Method in Form1 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 mySecondForm = new Form2(this);
    mySecondForm.Show();
}

// This is the second form which you opened from your first form..
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form someForm;

    public Form2(Form parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        someForm = parentForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someForm.Hide(); // Form1 should hide now
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks buddy. but btnLogin is in second form, I want to close the first form from second form.

Comment: Okay, so you might need to pass your current form to the second form via its constructor, let me edit the code. @KogulVimal

Comment: Okay waiting! @Shoaib Raza

Comment: Check now @KogulVimal

Comment: Cheers mate. @KogulVimal